# Change default value and class on submit button in Rails 4 ajax form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form_for submit button using ajax. The default button works fine.

```
<%= f.submit %>
```

But when I add a custom value and class, it fails silently.

```
<%= f.submit "Request a Visit", :class => "btn" %>
```

or

```
<%= f.submit "Request a Visit", class: "btn" %>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: it should work, are you getting any errors?

Comment: @Mandeep The screen flashes, but no errors in the console and no action is taken

Comment: can you inspect it and post what html it's generating also can you post your form

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I had conflicting javascript using the same class.